# Current Cursor Position in Percentages

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get current cursor position (xy coordinates) in percentages?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
            var xCord = getCurrentPos.pageX;
            var yCord = getCurrentPos.pageY;
            console.log(xCord+" "+yCord);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the total width of the page (x coord) in percentage to deal with responsive layout?

Comment: Percentages of _what_? The total height/width of the page?

Comment: @KevinBrown: i want width of page

Comment: I'd recommend you put that in the question then.

Comment: So, get the width of the page as well … and _calculate_ the percentage.

Comment: What do you want to do with the width? `console.log` it as a percentage? (xx%)

Comment: Calculating percentage is a trivial maths problem. Do you not know how to do this?

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight : I was using console.log for debugging purpose to check values generate successfully or not. The main aim is to get cursor position and fire some event on specific percentage

Comment: `( xCord / $( document ).width() * 100 )` will give you the percentage, I will update my answer to illustrate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put in a jquery [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) call, something like:

```
xPercent = xCord / $( document ).width() * 100;
console.log( xPercent + "%" );
```

(also note jQuery [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) call)

Answer (score 3):

`pageY` will take into account the offset of your browser header bar, you want to use `clientY` instead. In the following code, you will have `xPercent` and `yPercent` that go from 0 to 1 (multiply by 100 if you want an actual percentage).

```
$(document).mousemove(function(getCurrentPos){
    var xCord = getCurrentPos.clientX;
    var yCord = getCurrentPos.clientY;

    var xPercent = xCord/window.innerWidth;
    var yPercent = yCord/window.innerHeight;
});
```

Or since you are using jQuery, `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` are better for cross-browser concerns.

Answer (score 1):

use: `getCurrentPos.view.outerHeight`& `getCurrentPos.view.outerWidth`to get the actual size of height&width and then calc the percentage with what you already got.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is super old, and has an accepted answer, but I figured since it pops up on Google I'd provide a non-Jquery way, simple as it may be.

*I made this CodePen for easy reference:* https://codepen.io/DouglasGlover/pen/eYNPjwg

**HTML (for displaying numbers):**

```
Position X: <span id="posX">NaN</span>%<br/>
Position Y: <span id="posY">NaN</span>%
```

**CSS (to make body 100% height & width for the demo):**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: skyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

**Javascript (the magic):**

```
// Container and displays
const container = document.querySelector("body");
let posXDisplay = document.getElementById("posX");
let posYDisplay = document.getElementById("posY");

// On mousemove
container.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=> {
  // Do math
  xPercent = parseInt(e.pageX / window.innerWidth * 100);
  yPercent = parseInt(e.pageY / window.innerHeight * 100);

  // Display numbers
  posXDisplay.innerText = xPercent;
  posYDisplay.innerText = yPercent;
});
```